Accessing a static property in a generic interface
I created a generic interface that has a static property, and yet the classes that implement that interface do not seem to have access to the property or expose it to other code.
For example, the code below will not compile because TestClass.Empty cannot be resolved. I hope and expect that someone can explain to me why this is, and whether there is a way to modify the code to do what I would expect, such that the classes implementing the IEmpty interface need not have any code added to them to expose the Empty property.
public interface IEmpty<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public static virtual T Empty { get; } = new ();
}

public sealed class TestClass : IEmpty<TestClass>
{
    public bool IsEmpty => this == TestClass.Empty;
}

I'm sure the explanation is something I should know, but I guess you'll be the one telling me what it is.

If you just want to have a default static implementation that is not meant to be overridden in the classes implementing the interface, then remove the virtual modifier for the interface property:
public interface IEmpty<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public static T Empty { get; } = new();
}

public sealed class TestClass
{
    public bool IsEmpty => this == IEmpty<TestClass>.Empty;
}

As you see from the code above, you don't even need TestClass to implement the interface for this to work - any code can access the static property.
What might be useful is to restrict the accessibility to the scope of classes/interfaces that implement IEmpty<T>. You can do so by changing the property modifier to protected
public interface IEmpty<T> where T : class, new()
{
    protected static T Empty { get; } = new();
}

public sealed class TestClass : IEmpty<TestClass>
{
    public bool IsEmpty => this == IEmpty<TestClass>.Empty;
}


Thank you for your answer, but it does not accomplish my purpose.  I did indeed try the example code I posted both with and without the virtual keyword, and neither compiles.  Your modification to my example does not achieve my hoped-for goal, which was that TestClass.Empty would be an exposed property without any need to add code to the definition of TestClass itself (as the default implementation of None from the implemented interface should, I would think, be sufficient).

@ManusHand I thought you didn't post a duplicate...and tried to access the static method inside the class for which my second snippet provides a solution.

from your question and yet the classes that implement that interface do not seem to have access to the property or expose it to other code.

Hi @Ivan Petrov -- I am sorry if my question was unclear.  When I said "the classes that implement that interface do not seem to have access to the property or expose it to other code" I was saying that TestClass.Empty does not resolve, whether from code inside the implementation ot TestClass itself, or from code outside of TestClass.   I am hoping that everywhere in my code, I could simply use TestClass.None and not need to resort to using IEmpty<TestClass>.None.  Thanks again (oh, and yes, in my actual code, the accessibility of the objects, etc., is not always public.)

If you want each implementing class to expose an Empty property, you need to define it explicitly in the class:
public interface IEmpty<T> where T : class, new()
{
    bool IsEmpty { get; }
}

public sealed class TestClass : IEmpty<TestClass>
{
    public static TestClass Empty { get; } = new();

    public bool IsEmpty => this == TestClass.Empty;
}


Thank you but you seem to have misunderstood my question.  I wish to implement the static property Empty only in the interface, whose default implementation, I expected, should be exposed by TestClass by virtue of implementing the IEmpty interface.
